# Can't create a windows phone projectp

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to create a silverlight for windows phone Application.
But the following error appeared and I can't solve it:
**An update for Visual Studio is required to create a silverlight for windows phone application.
Download the Visual Studio update from:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=999999&clcid=0x0409**

I have these installed on my computer:
1. VS ultimate
2. Silverlight 5
3. Windows Phone SDK 7.1 
4. XNA 4.0
5. Silverlight toolkit 5
6. Silverlight for windows phone 5 toolkit december 2011
7. Microsft expression blend 4

Comment: Did you try installing the linked to update?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the latest service pack for Visual Studio?

If that doesn't work, you may need to uninstall/reinstall the phone SDK.